# Add value instead to datagridview if item already exist

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi guys here is my problem. I have 2 datagridview.

What i want to do is whenever i click "add this datagridview1 row(product) to datagridview2" and that product from datagridview1 is already in datagridview2, it will just add the value of a textbox(quantity) to the quantity cell in datagridview2 which have same ID as the one being inserted.

It can already detect if the product your inserting to datagridview2 is already existing but i cant make it add the value of the textbox to the existing cell in the datagridview.
Here are my codes(that is wrong and not working) and pic of the datagridviews.

```
    private bool alreadyincart()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrdercart.Rows)
        {
            int productcartID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvOrderproductlist.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) == productcartID)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item already exist, Adding the quantity instead.");
                int textboxquantity = Convert.ToInt32(bakss.Text);
                int dgvquantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
                int dgvnewquantity;
                dgvnewquantity = dgvquantity + textboxquantity;
                dgvOrdercart.Rows[productcartID].Cells[3].Value = dgvnewquantity;
                return false;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!validate())
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (!alreadyincart())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            addData(dgvOrderproductlist.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                dgvOrderproductlist.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                dgvOrderproductlist.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                bakss.Text, lblPrice.Text, totalprayss.Text, cboOrderSupplier.SelectedItem.ToString());           
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your logic is kind of backwards, making it harder to follow your code.  `alreadyincart()` returns false when the item **is** found in the cart, and true when it is not found.  That is the opposite of what it should be.

Comment: Yes i notice that sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
dgvOrdercart.Rows[productcartID].Cells[3].Value = dgvnewquantity;
```

to

```
row.Cells[3].Value = dgvnewquantity;
```

Comment: This is the answer.  Since the product id in row 0 of your cart 100103, your code is trying to access row 100103, not row 0.  There is no row 100103.